# Mailman "from" spoofing

Tags: email, mailing-list, mailman

It seems mailman, by default, spoofs its outgoing message with the "from" address of the person who posted the message. The envelope mail-from is not spoofed, but rather the P2 FROM. Is this configurable to d a send-on-behalf or simply change to some other static address?

Comment: (Begin unhelpful.) The From: header is defined to be the address of the person who logically originated the message. Mailman isn't spoofing it any more than it spoofs Date: or other headers is preserves. Why do you want to change it? (End unhelpful.)

Comment: some spam filters don't like the fact that mail is originating for a domain from an MTA that isn't allowed to send as that domain, even if it is a "soft spoof" of only the P2 FROM.

Comment: The From: address should never be a part of "spoof-filtering". The envelope sender (MAIL FROM) is used in SPF checks. They differ in your case and can differ.

Answer (score 6):

A bit old question, but here some suggestion solution.

I will try to explain how the default mailman behavior.

Email from member1@example.com was sent to lists@example.net (a mailman list). Both **envelope sender** and lists-bounces@example.net  have value "member@example.com".

As mailman receive it, it rewrites **envelope sender** to lists-bounces@example.net. Now mailman forward it to other members with **envelope sender: lists-bounces@example.net** and **From header: member@example.com**.

The problem is, as April 2014 the Big Email Provider [Yahoo activates DMARC in their domains](http://blog.returnpath.com/blog/christine-borgia/all-about-yahoos-dmarc-reject-policy). As the result, if DMARC-aware mail server spot the Yahoo address in **From header** but it wasn't sent from Yahoo server, the server will reject it.

---

Mailman developer adding fix in Mailman version 2.1.16. It now has [option from_is_list](https://wiki.list.org/DOC/Mailman%202.1%20List%20Administrators%20Manual#line-163)

> **from_is_list**
>
> Replace the sender with the list address to conform with policies like ADSP and DMARC. It replaces the poster's address in the From: header with the list address and adds the poster to the Reply-To: header, but the anonymous_list and Reply-To: header munging settings below take priority. If setting this to Yes, it is advised to set the MTA to DKIM sign all emails.
> If this is set to Wrap Message, just wrap the message in an outer message From: the list with Content-Type: message/rfc822

Answer (score 0):

See @masegaloeh's answer for details.  Here is a way to apply that setting in bulk:

```py
# updatelist_from_is_list.py

import sys

class UserDesc: pass

def updatelist_from_is_list(mlist):
    if mlist is None:
        return

    mlist.from_is_list = 1
    mlist.Save()
```

Above for `mlist.from_is_list`:

- 0 is off
- 1 is "munge from"
- 2 is "wrap"

Then apply the script as follows:

```bash
cd /usr/lib/mailman/bin/
./withlist -l -r updatelist_from_is_list LISTNAME
```

Note that the file is named `updatelist_from_is_list.py` but when does not end in `.py` when passed to `withlist`.

For lots of lists:

```bash
/usr/lib/mailman/bin/list_lists -b | while read mlist; do 
    /usr/lib/mailman/bin/withlist -l -r updatelist_from_is_list $mlist
done
```